# boto3 not able to perform if condition on response

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying use describe_alarms using boto3 sdk, for my aws account.

when i'm trying to do if condition on response but its not working,

code:-

```
for i in alarm['MetricAlarms']:
  if i['MetricName] == 'Myalarm':
     print(i[AlarmName])
     print("done")
```

o/p :- done , instead of name of alarm associated

above code will be parsing below response

```
{
'MetricAlarms': [
    {
        'AlarmName': 'string',
        'AlarmArn': 'string',
        'AlarmDescription': 'string',
        'AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
        'ActionsEnabled': True|False,
        'OKActions': [
            'string',
        ],
        'AlarmActions': [
            'string',
        ],
        'InsufficientDataActions': [
            'string',
        ],
        'StateValue': 'OK'|'ALARM'|'INSUFFICIENT_DATA',
        'StateReason': 'string',
        'StateReasonData': 'string',
        'StateUpdatedTimestamp': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
        'MetricName': 'string',
        'Namespace': 'string',
        'Statistic': 'SampleCount'|'Average'|'Sum'|'Minimum'|'Maximum',
        'ExtendedStatistic': 'string',
        'Dimensions': [
            {
                'Name': 'string',
                'Value': 'string'
            },
        ],
        'Period': 123,
        'Unit': 'Seconds'|'Microseconds'|'Milliseconds'|'Bytes'|'Kilobytes'|'Megabytes'|'Gigabytes'|'Terabytes'|'Bits'|'Kilobits'|'Megabits'|'Gigabits'|'Terabits'|'Percent'|'Count'|'Bytes/Second'|'Kilobytes/Second'|'Megabytes/Second'|'Gigabytes/Second'|'Terabytes/Second'|'Bits/Second'|'Kilobits/Second'|'Megabits/Second'|'Gigabits/Second'|'Terabits/Second'|'Count/Second'|'None',
        'EvaluationPeriods': 123,
        'DatapointsToAlarm': 123,
        'Threshold': 123.0,
        'ComparisonOperator': 'GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold'|'GreaterThanThreshold'|'LessThanThreshold'|'LessThanOrEqualToThreshold',
        'TreatMissingData': 'string',
        'EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile': 'string'
    },
],
'NextToken': 'string'
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
print(i[AlarmName])
```

It should be:

```
print(i['AlarmName'])
```

However, I always check to see if a key is in a dict before access. Your code will crash if the API changes, an error is returned, etc.:

```
if 'MetricAlarms' in alarm:
  for i in alarm['MetricAlarms']:
    if 'MetricName' in i:
        if i['MetricName] == 'Myalarm':
           print(i['AlarmName'])
           print("done")
```

Comment: Thanks John, print(i['AlarmName']) was corrected in code, will try out code you have provided